# Running the WSO2EI

Tags: eclipse, microservices, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I started the system based on the following address:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/Quick+Start+Guide

1.**ESB**, **Business Process** and **Analytics** profiles came up. But the json request will not be sent. total requests for Healthcare API is zero. Have you ever had such an experience? What is your proposed solution for the problem?

2.My another problem with the **WSO2 Developer Studio**. I downloaded it. How can I write a HelloWorld in this program as a **micro-service**. For example, whenever a specific request came, it would display a HelloWorld page.

3. When I compile a HelloWorld program, I encounter to this error. **Manifest entry 'microservices' not found when deploying**

4.Is there a specialty forum for wso2?

Comment: Hi, about 1. Were able to execute the curlcommand and succesfully send the JSON request? Please elaborate what in what step and action you were running into problems. Any errors in the logging?

Comment: I successfully log in and the curl request was successfully sent but in Healthcare API, numbers of requests is zero.